# How to invoke HTTP PUT from URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Scenario:-
I have a form, once user submits this form, a mail is sent to user.
As usual an activation link is present in the mail body.

And if the user click on the Link, he is redirected to the page,now on visit of the url, I want to update the field in my DB table :-

1. **isEmailVerfied** to **true**
2. **DateOfVerification**

I am using WebAPI and **HTTPPUT** action to update the database.
 
ControllerName is **Registration**, I don't want the user to click on any extra button to update, I want if the user visits the url, HTTPPut(or update) operation should be called and that links to be invalid, once user clicked.

Comment: and where are you now stuck with? sending a Put Request with Javascript or?

Comment: Just too be clear, are you trying to update some fields in a database when the user clicks on a link?

Comment: Just to note as well you can't specify the httpmethod put in the URL you need to modify the request header for that. So you can do that with fiddler for example

Comment: @Mark..its not hitting the HTTPPut acion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the flow of actions in this scenario is something like this:

1. User fills out a form on a webpage
2. User submits form to your web api backend
3. The backend saves the data submitted from the form
4. The backend sends out an email containing a link to your application
5. User reads email and clicks on the link

And you want the action in step 5 here to trigger some other action in your backend, which is to update some data in your database which you have already implemented and have exposed as as a `http PUT` method in your api.

The problem is that clicking on a link from an email that opens up in a browser is that you cannot specify the `http` method. Navigating to URLs in a browser, which is what you are doing, is a `GET` request. So your `PUT` action will never get hit.

To resolve this you can just change your action from `PUT` to `GET`.

change this:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("verify/{hash}")
public void VerifyEmail(string hash){
   // your implementation logic
}
```

to this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("verify/{hash}")
public void VerifyEmail(string hash){
   // your implementation logic
}
```